# Problems with returning a row in MySQL, ASP

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, recordset

I'm just making the switch from ASP/Access to ASP/MYSQL

I'm working with the default tables in MYSQL.

I'm trying to write a query that counts the records and will allow me to list the contents at the same time.

```
"SELECT * FROM world.city ORDER BY Name ASC"
```

I am trying to combine a `SELECT COUNT () AS`, with a full list.

I can achieve them as seperate queries, but not together. I've tried:

```
"SELECT Name, SELECT COUNT(*) AS iTotal FROM world.city ORDER BY Name ASC"
```

But it only returns one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT Name, COUNT(*) AS iTotal
    FROM world.city
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
   Name,
   (
    SELECT
       COUNT(*)
    FROM
       world.city
   ) AS iTotal 
FROM
   world.city
ORDER BY
   Name ASC
```